# Is this the right way to do callback in js?

Tags: javascript, callback

```
function first(i, callback){
    var img_full_url = S3.getSignedUrl('getObject', {
      Bucket: BUCKET,
      Key: result.data[i].picture_url
    });
    callback(i, img_full_url);
  }

  function second(i, img_full_url, callback){
    $('#img_holder').after(`<img id="img${i}" src= "${img_full_url}" crossorigin>`);
    callback(i);
  }

  function third(i, callback){
    var img = document.querySelector(`#img${i}`);
    img.addEventListener('load', function(event) {
      var dataUrl = getDataUrl(event.currentTarget);
      callback(i, dataUrl);
    });
  }

  function forth(i, dataUrl){
    zip.file(`${result.data[i].picture_url}.txt`, dataUrl);
  }

  for(var i = 0; i<3; i++){
    first(i, function(i, img_full_url){
      second(i, img_full_url, function(i){
        third(i, function(i, dataUrl){
          forth(i, dataUrl);
        });
      });
    });
  }
```

The code above gave me the output I want.
However I'm new to the callback things and js.
And this tangled thing look ridiculous to me.
Is this the right way to do it in order to make the code running in order?

Comment: The JS world has moved on to Promises due to the so called `callback hell` which is what you call `tangled` and `ridiculous`. Read on `Promises` and `async/await`.

Comment: It does look ridiculous since it is:D Thats why Promises are kinda replacing callbacks all over the place. Chaining is cleaner then nesting.

Comment: since there's nothing asynchronous about `first` and `second`, you've made it more complicated than it needs to be

Comment: @JaromandaX while that is true, I think this is an illustrative example. In addition, can also easily have non-async functions that take a callback for some customizable part of their behaviour.